# Syntax: Compacted For Loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is going on here?

```
with open('contractors.txt','r') as in_file:  
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)   
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
```

Is this a syntactic equivalent to:

```
for line in in_file:
    stripped = line.strip()
for line in stripped:
    lines =  line
```

Comment: yes, these are same.

Comment: No! Because in the second case `stripped` only has the last value from the file...

Comment: Also `lines` would be the last letter from the last line.

Comment: So in the first one, is it actually appending to an array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does a generator comprehension work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work)

Answer (score 0):

The "compacted for loops" are called [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), which are more-or-less equivalent to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that return generators instead of lists.

In the code you're looking at, the `stripped` generator expression `str.strip()`s each line of the opened file, and the `lines` generator expression drops any blank lines from `stripped`. The end result is a generator (`lines`) that, when iterated over, will generate the stripped version of the non-empty lines of the file.

It's important to note that since you're just working with generators, after these lines are run *nothing has actually been read from the file yet*. If you end the `with` block, the file will be closed and attempting to pull anything from `lines` will result in an I/O error. So anything you want to do with it has to be done within that block.