# How to determine the maximum scrabble score stored in a file?

Tags: python

I got a list of points for each letter:

```
SCRABBLES_SCORES = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
                    (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
```

And in file I have to find word with the highest score

I have a problem, because I don't know how to examine new line.
I tried this, but its never ending loop:

```
max = 0
help = 0
file = open("dictionary.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    for l in line:
        while(l != '\n'):
            help += LETTER_SCORES.get(l)
            if(help > max):
                max = help
            else:
                continue
    help = 0

print(max)
```

Does anybody know what Im doing wrong?

[**Edit**] Mapping for dictionary:

```
LETTER_SCORES = {letter: score for score, letters in SCRABBLES_SCORES
                    for letter in letters.split()}
```

Comment: `while(l != '\n'):` is an infinite loop because `l` never changes inside the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Your structure is the wrong way round. For the scale of this problem, use a dictionary that maps letters as _keys_ to their points as _values_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [generator comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work) for a cleaner and clearer answer:

```
words = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']  # this simulates the words in your file

max(sum(LETTER_SCORES[c.upper()] for c in word) for word in words)  # returns 14 for 'baz'
```

You can read your file as follows:

```
with open("dictionary.txt") as f:
    words = list(f)
```

Comment: It work fine for file with 1 word. If there is more than 1 I got an error: KeyError: 'n'

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop is causing your error.

Say the first line began with the letter `'a'`, then the condition `l != '\n'` will be true and won't change during the iterations of the while loop, so you get stuck there.

You don't need the `while` loop altogether.