# How can you approximate the value of an infinite series in python?

Tags: python, math

I am messing about and wanted to use python to evaluate the following series

1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 + .....

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Loop until python breaks.

Comment: Awesome! Sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers do math pretty fast.  Just give it a big number:

```
>>> sum(1/n**2 for n in range(1, 1000000))
1.64493306684777
```

If you want it to be within a specific level of precision, you could make this a little more complicated by iterating until the difference in successive answers gets below a certain threshold.  If you don't care about the exact precision or the exact runtime, just pick a number that's arbitrarily "big enough" but not so big that it'll take "too long".  I just arbitrarily said "a million" in the above example, which makes it accurate to more decimal places than you're likely to care about and still takes well under a second.

Comment: Should note that you **should not** use list comprehensions here - use generators that save on memory.

Comment: Yup -- this example is a generator because there are no square brackets (`[]`).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work

Answer (score 2):

```py
n = 1
s = 0
while True:
    s  += 1/n**2
    n += 1
    print(s, end="\r")
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> when you're happy! :)