# How can I concatenate numbers from two lists by indices into a tuple using yield?(Python)

Tags: python, list, function, concatenation, yield

I need to make a "generator function" which will take 2 lists and concatenate numbres from two lists by indices into a tuple. For example:

```
l1 = [3, 2, 1]
l2 = [4, 3, 2]
```

The result of the first iteration will be
`(3, 4)`
The result of the second iteration will be
`(2, 3)`
And the third
`(1, 2)`
And also, one of lists may have more numbers than the other one. In that case I need to write condition "if one of the lists ended while iterating, then no further iterations are performed." (using `try, except`)

I know, that generator functions use `yield` instead of `return`, but I have no idea how to write this fuction...
I did this

```
def generate_something(l1, l2):
    l3 = tuple(tuple(x) for x in zip(l1, l2))
    return l3
```

output is

```
((3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2))
```

It works, but this is not geterator function, there is no `yield`, there is no first-,second-,etc- iterations. I hope you can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own generator:

```
def iterate_lists(l1,l2):
   for i,item in enumerate(l1):
       yield l1[i],l2[i]
```

or as a variable by [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work):

```
iterate_lists = (li[i],l2[i] for i,item in enumerate(l1))
```

about if the lengthes arent equal its not clear to me what exactly you want to do,  without the message you can just go on the smaller list...
just change the `for i,item in enumerate(l1)`  with `for i in range(min((len(l1),len(l2)))`

Comment: yes, i tried this too, but when i write ```yield``` the output is ```<generator object iterate_lists at 0x0349D958>``` which is not what the task asks

Comment: because it is a generator, what excactly do you want to print? you can just use the function `next()` on the generator to iterate over it...

Answer (score 2):

May be this help for you:

```
def generate_something_2(l1, l2):
    # if one of the lists ended while iterating, then no further iterations are performed.
    # For this get minimal len of list
    min_i = len(l1) if len(l1) < len(l2) else len(l2)
    for i in range(0,min_i):
        yield (l1[i], l2[i])

l1 = [3, 2, 1, 1]
l2 = [4, 3, 2]

l3 = tuple(generate_something_2(l1, l2))
# Result: ((3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2))
print(l3)
```

Comment: yes, it works too. But don't you know how can I print at first the first iteration, then the second iteration, and then the third one?

I did ```l3 = tuple(next(generate_something_2(l1, l2)))``` in your code. But it prints only the first iteration when i write print(l3)

Comment: I got it. I did this
```l3 = generate_something_2([3, 2, 1, 1], [4, 3, 2])
print(next(l3))
print(next(l3))
print(next(l3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop and keep track of the index position, when a `IndexError` is raised you've hit the end of the shortest list and stop:

```
def generate_something(l1, l2):
    idx = 0
    while True:
        try:
            yield l1[idx], l2[idx]
            idx += 1
        except IndexError:
            break


l1 = [3, 2, 1]
l2 = [4, 3, 2]

g = generate_something(l1, l2)
print(list(g))
```

Output:

```
[(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: if i do ```print(next(g))``` 4 times instead of ```print(list(g))```, than there is an Error ```StopIteration```, do you know how to fix this Error? I tried to write 
```except StopIteration``` but it doesn't work

Comment: that `StopIteration` lets the caller know the generator is exhausted. `list(g)` handles this implicitly, you would need to write some code outside of `generate_something()` when calling `next(g)` multiple times.