# Luhn algorithm id number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the Luhn algorithm to find ids check number.
for Example - input - 12345678 , output - 2.
I'm trying to do it in the most efficient way possible, as well as in the fewest lines possible.
So far I wrote this :

```
ID = input("Enter your first 8 digits of your id : ")
print(10 - sum(map(lambda a: a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]), [int(ID[i]) if i % 2 
== 0 else int(ID[i]) * 2 for i in range(8)])) % 10) # if digit is 0 prints 10
```

I'm not satisfied with the int string conversions.
But I'm Looking for any improvement.

Comment: Err, it would really help if you could rewrite your code in a long, readable version just for us !

Comment: Ah, here you go : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn-Algorithmus#Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and welcome to StackOverflow!

### Super short, but with a dependency

If you can rely on external dependencies, take a look at the [`luhn` package](https://pypi.org/project/luhn/). You can install it with `pip install luhn`, and then your program becomes:

```py
from luhn import generate

ID = input("Enter your first 8 digits of your id : ")
print(generate(ID))
```

Can't get much cleaner than this.

### Changing your code

But let's suppose you don't want to use a third-party package. Let us first put your code in a function and format it:

```py
def luhn(number):
    return (
        10 - sum(
            map(
                lambda a: a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]),
                [
                    int(number[i])
                    if i % 2 == 0
                    else int(number[i]) * 2
                    for i in range(8)
                ]
            )
        ) % 10
    )
```

#### Step 1: `list` to generator

You can simply replace your list comprehension with a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/364824/5811400) to make it a bit faster since you don't need to build the whole list first:

```py
def luhn(number):
    return (
        10 - sum(
            map(
                lambda a: a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]),
                ( # <--- changed this
                    int(number[i])
                    if i % 2 == 0
                    else int(number[i]) * 2
                    for i in range(8)
                ) # <--- changed this
            )
        ) % 10
    )
```

#### Step 2: Get rid of `map`

I personally don't like using `map` when you have to write a lambda as well. It just kills the two purposes of `map`: simpler code and fast, C-speed execution.

For instance, `map(int, myseq)` is great, extremely fast and clean. But `map(lambda x: int(x), myseq)` is cumbersome (you have to give a name `x` to `myseq` items) and slow (because lambdas don't benefit from the C-like speed of builtin functions). In this case, I would say that `int(x) for x in myseq` reads much nicer.

Applying that to the previous function:

```py
def luhn(number):
    return (
        10 - sum(
            a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1])
            for a in (
                int(number[i])
                if i % 2 == 0
                else int(number[i]) * 2
                for i in range(8)
            ) # bonus: we have one less indentation level!
        ) % 10
    )
```

#### Step 3: Get rid of one `if-else`

In the second `for` loop, we have `x if i % 2 == 0 else x * 2` where `x = int(number[i])`. But since `i % 2` is either `0` or `1`, you can benefit from this and write `x * (1 + i%2)`. So our function becomes:

```py
def luhn(number):
    return (
        10 - sum(
            a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1])
            for a in (int(number[i]) * (1 + i%2) for i in range(8))
        ) % 10
    )
```

Getting prettier, right?

#### Step 4: Split "even" and "odd" characters

Now think with me. When will `i % 2` be equal to `0` and when will it be `1`? It is `0` when `i` is even, and `1` when `i` is odd. So, in the expression `int(number[i]) * (1 + i%2)`, we will have `int(number[i])` when `i` is even, and `int(number[i]) * 2` when `i` is odd. Supposing that `number` is `314159`, then the "even characters" (characters in even positions) `345` are returned as-is, and the "odd characters" `119` are multiplied by `2`.

Moreover, the expression `a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1])` is also trivial for even characters: since they are returned as-is, they obviously satisfy `a <= 9`, and then they are also returned as-is.

Noting that even and odd characters can be obtained by slicing:

```py
s = 314159
even = s[::2] # 345
odd = s[1::2] # 119
```

So we can split our function into two parts. It gets bigger now, but afterwards it'll get better:

```py
def luhn(number):
    evens = number[::2]
    even_sum = sum(map(int, evens)) # sum even characters

    odds = number[1::2]
    odd_sum = sum(
        a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1])
        for a in (int(odd) * 2 for odd in odds)
    ) # sum odd characters

    return (
        10 - (even_sum + odd_sum) % 10
    )
```

#### Step 5: More refactoring

In "`a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1])`", what this piece of code is saying is: sum the digits of `a`. Because, if `a` has only one digit (`a <= 9`) we are just returning it; otherwise, we are summing its first and second digits.

But then, taking a closer look, we are summing this sum of digits for all numbers yielded by `str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in odds`! This means that we can first concatenate all the digits, and then sum them all:

```py
def luhn(number):
    evens = number[::2]
    even_sum = sum(map(int, evens)) # sums even characters

    odds = number[1::2]
    multiplied_by_two = (str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in odds)
    all_digits = ''.join(multiplied_by_two)
    odd_sum = sum(map(int, all_digits))

    return (
        10 - (even_sum + odd_sum) % 10
    )
```

And we finally merge the two sums into one:

```py
def luhn(number):
    evens = number[::2]

    odds = number[1::2]
    multiplied_by_two = (str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in odds)
    all_digits = ''.join(multiplied_by_two)

    total_sum = sum(map(int, evens + all_digits))

    return (
        10 - total_sum % 10
    )
```

Now we just collapse into a single expression:

```py
def luhn(number):
    return (
        10 - sum(
            map(
                int,
                number[::2] + ''.join(
                    str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in number[1::2]
                )
            )
        ) % 10
    )
```

Finally, we make it a one-liner and finish your program:

```py
ID = input("Enter your first 8 digits of your id : ")
print(10 - sum(map(int, ID[::2] + ''.join(str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in ID[1::2]))) % 10)
```

### Some metrics

By comparing our solutions:

```py
import timeit

ID = '12345678'
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: 10 - sum(map(lambda a: a if a <= 9 else int(str(a)[0]) + int(str(a)[1]), [int(ID[i]) if i % 2
== 0 else int(ID[i]) * 2 for i in range(8)])) % 10, number=1000000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: 10 - sum(map(int, ID[::2] + ''.join(str(int(odd) * 2) for odd in ID[1::2]))) % 10, number=1000000))
```

you can see that the latter is ~30% faster.