# How would i write a line of code on python that adds up 100 random numbers through 1 to 6?

Tags: python, windows

I have this code (I know why it's wrong I just don't know how I could fix it)

```
import random

x = 0

for i in range(100):
    print(x + (random.randint(1, 6)))
```

Please could somebody help or point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't add up numbers:

```
import random

x = 0
for i in range(100):
    x += random.randint(1, 6)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer.

```
import random
x = sum([random.randint(1,6) for i in range(100)])
```

Comment: Probably a good idea not to show a person who cannot write a straightforward loop a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the final sum:

```
from random import randint

x = 0
for i in range(100):
    x += randint(1, 6)
print(x)
```

Eden Yosef's answer is the best to do the same thing in Python since it uses comprehension but I wanted to add this incase you haven't gotten to comprehension yet.

Daniel's will print every time it sums, which is how you formatted yours.

Answer (score 1):

The previous two answers lack an explanation, so here it is:

In your code, you are adding the random number - but the problem is, you are not adding that random number to `x` itself, but just printing out `x` plus the random number. This means your loop is doing this:

```
print(0 + random.randint(1, 6))
print(0 + random.randint(1, 6))
print(0 + random.randint(1, 6))
# ...
```

Basically, `x` is always `0`. In order to fix this, you would have to add the random number to `x` itself, and then print `x`. Additionally, you don't want to print every time you add, but once at the end - so take the `print` outside of the `for` loop:

```
import random

x = 0

for i in range(100):
    x += random.randint(1, 6)
print(x)
```

However, this can also be solved using [`generator comprehension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work)s:

```py
import random
x = sum(random.randint(1, 6) for i in range(100))
print(x)
```

Comment: *generator expression

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

x = sum([random.randint(1,6) for i in range(100)])
print(x)
```