# Odoo - Iterate through field, take the values and put them in a new field

Tags: python, function, loops, odoo, one2many

Hay I am new to Odoo Customizing and Python and wanted to know how I can iterate through a field and take the values out of the field and put them in a  new one.

The field I want to iterate through contains multiple email adresses. I want to iterate through these email adress fields, collect the email adresses and store them together in a new field.

For that I need a function.

The field I want to iterate through:
My One2many field contains multiple mail adresses which I want to iterate through and collect.

```
field_contacts_customer_info = fields.One2many(
        'contacts.customer.information', 'another_id', string='Contacts for customer information')
```

The field I want to store the collected email adresses in:

```
selected_email = fields.Char(compute='compute_email')
```

This is my class:
I want to collect all the email adresses from the mail_contacts field.

```
    _name = 'contacts.customer.information'
    _rec_name = 'name_contacts'

    name_contacts = fields.Many2one(
        'res.partner', string="Person", domain = [('is_company', '=', False)])

    mail_contacts = fields.Char(
        related = 'name_contacts.email' ,string="Email")

    another_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="AnotherID")
```

My Try: This function collects only the last set record of the `field_contacts_customer_info` field and puts this record in the selected_email field of every company.So it does not work right. It should collect  all the mails of the `field_contacts_customer_info` field for every company seperated and then put them in the `selected_mail` field of the belonging company.

```
@api.onchange('field_contacts_customer_info.mail_contacts')
def compute_email(self): 
        list_email = [] 
        for record in self: 
            if record.is_company: 
                for element in record.field_contacts_customer_info: 
                    if element.name_contacts: 
                        list_email.append(element.mail_contacts) 
                    for email in list_email: 
                        self.selected_email = email
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over `self` which is a record set and loop over `field_contacts_customer_info` field to get `mail_contacts` field values.

```py
@api.depends('field_contacts_customer_info.mail_contacts')
def get_email(self):
    for record in self:
        record.selected_email = ','.join(info.mail_contacts for info in record.field_contacts_customer_info if info.mail_contacts)
```

Then set the `compute` attribute to `get_email`:

```
selected_email = fields.Char(string="Mail4Info", compute='get_email')
```

You can check the ORM documentation on how to use the [computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#computed-fields).

***Edit (compute method):***

You are setting the value of `selected_email` to each element of `list_email`, after the `compute_email` is executed the value of `selected_email` will always be the last value of `list_email`.

The last for loop is executed each time we loop over `record.field_contacts_customer_info`, it should be at the same level as the second loop.

The `list_email` is declared before we loop over records (it is not reset in the loop), after the first record, each record will use the email values of previous records.

When `record.is_company` is evaluated to `False`, the compute method will not assign a field value, you should see the following error:

```
ValueError: Compute method failed to assign {record description}.selected_email
```

It happens because the compute method must assign a field value

***Example:***

```
@api.depends('field_contacts_customer_info.mail_contacts')
def compute_email(self):
    for record in self:
        list_email = []
        if record.is_company:
            for element in record.field_contacts_customer_info:
                if element.name_contacts:
                    list_email.append(element.mail_contacts)
            emails = ""
            for email in list_email:
                emails += email + " "
            record.selected_email = emails
        else:
            record.selected_email = ""
```

You can change the `list_email` type to a string and avoid looping again to get the field value:

***Example:***

```
@api.depends('field_contacts_customer_info.mail_contacts')
def compute_email(self):
    for record in self:
        list_email = ""
        if record.is_company:
            for element in record.field_contacts_customer_info:
                if element.name_contacts:
                    list_email += element.mail_contacts
        record.selected_email = list_email
```

Comment: thank you! Maybe you can proof if I understood it right: The '@api.depends' keeps an eye on the 'field_contacts_customer_info.mail_contacts' - field and is triggered whenever ist changes. When '@api.depends' is triggered the function get_email is called which has the parameter self, that represents an object in my class. for every record so for every email adress in this case we add the record to the selected_email - field by saying record.selected_email and after that I am a little bit lost the comma seperates the records. Maybe you can explain the part after that so that I can understand.

Comment: Yes and `self` can represent multiple records. I used the comma just to separate the email addresses. The `get_email` method must assign the computed value to the field.

Comment: Thank you! I got one question left. You used "info." where does that come from and what does it do or represent ?

Comment: It represents a  `contacts.customer.information` record. I used a [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work) and iterated over `field_contacts_customer_info` using `info` variable name

Comment: Does this answer help you?

Comment: Yes you helped me at that time and it worked finde on my machine. When I tried putting my code on the live machine I got an error with that code: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found" Do you have an idea why this appears ? For me the compute attribute is confusing, you think it could be because of this attribute ? is there another way that I can add the "join-string" into the selected_email field ? Thanks

Comment: This happens because at least one `mail_contacts` field is not defined, you can resolve the error by adding a condition in the join call. I updated my answer

Comment: By not defined you mean that there is no content in it or rather that there is no email address in at least one one the mail_contacts fields ?

Comment: I mean the value is not set (Defaults to ``False``)

Comment: so when we do not give the if condition the mail_contacts field has the value false which is why we get the error "bool found". And by giving the if condition we are saying that the join should only happen when mail_contacts has a value ?

Comment: Yes, we use the if condition to filter out the boolean `mail_contacts` values

Comment: hay, today I tried out your idea on the live machine but it did not work. I can enter the view without getting an error now, but the mail adresses are not added into the selected_email field.

Comment: Did you use the `store` attribute?

Comment: No. I try avoiding the join statement now, because I think it it does not work with the databank of the live machine for me. I updated my question and showed my new code. Maybe you can help.

Comment: It will save only the last value in the list, check my edit

Comment: I just noticed that you changed the decorator to `onchange` but you used dotted field names which are not supported. You can check the waring at [odoo.api.onchange(*args)](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange). ``@onchange`` only supports simple field names, dotted names (fields of relational fields ``e.g. partner_id.tz``) are not supported and ``will be ignored``

Comment: @kayalotta Does this answer your question?