# I am confused about where the r in the below code

Tags: python

I am confused about where the `r` in the below code comes from in the `combinations` function. A bit new to Python.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Comment: From `for r in range(len(s)+1)`.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `r` is the iterable of the generator comprehension statement passed to the function `chain.from_iterable()`. If you unpack the comprehension, it would be analogous to the below code.

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    res = []
    for r in range(len(s) + 1):
        res.append(combinations(s, r))
    return chain.from_iterable(res)
```

Both the above `for` loop and the provided generator comprehension use the variable `r` as the iterator.

You can read more about generator comprehension from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work) Stack Overflow answer. While not identical, you can read more about list comprehension in the Python Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).