# How to count how many times I got the certain result

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

I am trying to write a code that would select 5 numbers between 1-10 and choose the maximum of them. I repeat the experiment 1000 times but I want to see how many times ı get the which result

```
import random
for i in range (1,1000):
    b = random.choices(range(1, 11), k=5)
    max(b)
    print("The X value for %(n)s is {%(c)s} " % {'n': b, 'c': max(b)})
```

I want to see something like 10 occurring 500 times, 9 occurring 300 times. I tried to define a dictionary but couldn't manage to do so. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try and use Counter. It's a special dict that does what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(1, 1000):
    numbers = random.choices(range(1, 11), k=5)
    counter[max(numbers)] += 1
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {10: 406, 8: 161, 9: 269, 7: 86, 6: 40, 5: 25, 4: 10, 3: 2})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/how-exactly-does-a-generator-comprehension-work) like this:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(max(random.choices(range(1, 11), k=5)) for _ in range(1, 1000))
```

Example output:

```
Counter({10: 388, 9: 281, 8: 161, 7: 91, 6: 41, 5: 23, 4: 10, 3: 4})
```

Comment: `dict(Counter(max(random.choices(range(1, 11), k=5)) for _ in range(1, 1000)))`
 to get a dict instead of a counter object

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with all the necessary keys, and then add 1 to the value each time that key comes up.

```py
import random
number_counts = {x:0 for x in range(1,11)} # this will create a dictionary with 1-10 as keys and 0 as values
for i in range(1,1000):
    b = random.choices(range(1,11),k=5)
    m = max(b)
    number_counts[m] += 1

print(number_counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the *.count()* method. Quite simple TBF. Here's how it works, in google's words.

The method is applied to a given list and takes a single argument. The argument passed into the method is counted and the number of occurrences of that item in the list is returned.

Comment: Credit for quote: https://datagy.io/python-count-occurrences-in-list/

Comment: `count` is great for getting the count of just one value. For multiple values, it still works, but it has to iterate through the whole list again each time.