# How to shorten long "and" statements?

Tags: python, python-2.7, coding-style, pep8

I have a looong statement of "and"'s, for example:

```
if this == that and this == that and this == that:
    do this
```

How to correctly break such statements into separate lines, to comply with PEP-8?

Comment: Generally by avoiding them; code that has that many `and` statements usually can be refactored in to something a little more readable.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/python-style-multiple-line-conditions-in-ifs

Comment: Using `all` helps, slightly..

Comment: Do you mean like `this1 == that1 and this2 == that2`?

Comment: Yes Janne, of course.

Answer (score 3):

[PEP8 gives a recommendation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation. Make sure to indent the continued line
>   appropriately. The preferred place to break around a binary operator
>   is after the operator, not before it.

and examples:

```
if (width == 0 and height == 0 and
    color == 'red' and emphasis == 'strong' or
    highlight > 100):
    raise ValueError("sorry, you lose")
if width == 0 and height == 0 and (color == 'red' or
                                   emphasis is None):
    raise ValueError("I don't think so -- values are %s, %s" %
                     (width, height))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can separate lines in Python, but mark them to be the same "semantic" line, by inserting backslashes:

```
if     this == that \
   and this == that \
   and this == that:
    do this
```

This will do even if you have `and`'s or `or`'s in your complex conditional expression.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have to do that, then use `(...)` parenthesis and avoid the backslashes altogether. `if (this == that and this == that and\n    this == that):`

Comment: -1 The question is asking for PEP-8 compliance and PEP-8 recommends paranthesis