# Can not get past illogical line pep8 error

Tags: python, if-statement, pep8

I've been trying to fix this for a while now and I just can't get it to pass [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).
Here is my code:

1.

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and 
    sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and 
    regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```

2. 

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and 
    sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and 
    regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```

3. 

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' 
    and regex.count('(') > 1):
        
    print('hi')
```

I get the following PEP8 error on each of the 3 `if` statements:

```
E125 continuation line does not distinguish itself from next logical line
```

Any idea on what's wrong with it? The lines are indented with parenthesis so i really don't have any clue.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: pep8 gives me the following error: regex_functions_draft.py:44:9: E125 continuation line does not distinguish itself from next logical line. I tried indenting it correctly with the first bracket but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @FredMitchell regex is just a variable and isn't relevant. The if statement works, it's just how pep8 handled how i indented the if statement.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/python-style-multiple-line-conditions-in-ifs

Comment: There's also an interesting bug report about this issue on the PEP8 module's github page: https://github.com/jcrocholl/pep8/issues/126

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1.

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and
        sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and
        regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```

2.

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and
        sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and
        regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```

3.

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')'
        and regex.count('(') > 1):

    print('hi')
```

Comment: As a newbie to python, I had scrolled up and down 3 times until I noticed the indention difference. :)

Comment: [There](https://github.com/PyCQA/pep8/issues/126) has a brief description and I quote here:  Here is the relevant statement from pep8:
Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets
and braces, or using a hanging indent. When using a hanging indent
the following considerations should be applied; there should be no
arguments on the first line and further indentation should be used
to clearly distinguish itself as a continuation line.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (which is pretty good for pointing out PEP8 errors) for my editing, and it says this version is ok:

```
if (len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and
        sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and
        regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```

Comment: This seems awkward to me, since the `sum` and `regex.count` lines are not aligned with the parenthesis that they're nested in. It looks like they're part of the `len` call, while they're outside of it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not saying I love this solution, but I think that removing the space after `if` is less of a compromise than lining up the second line with the guts of the `len` call, like the other answers here suggest:

```
if(len(regex) > 2 and regex[0] == '(' and regex[-1] == ')' and
   sum(regex.count(char) for char in splitter) == 1 and
   regex.count('(') == 1 and regex.count(')') == 1):

    print('hi')
```