# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - Error when calling a function

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe

I know following error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

has been asked a long time ago.

However, I am trying to create a basic function and return a new column with `df['busy']` with `1` or `0`. My function looks like this,

```
def hour_bus(df):
    if df[(df['hour'] >= '14:00:00') & (df['hour'] <= '23:00:00')&\
             (df['week_day'] != 'Saturday') & (df['week_day'] != 'Sunday')]:
         return df['busy'] == 1
     else:
         return df['busy'] == 0
```

I can execute the function, but when I call it with the DataFrame, I get the error mentioned above. I followed the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) and another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/styling-multi-line-conditions-in-if-statements) to create that function.  I used `&` instead of `and` in my `if` clause.

Anyhow, when I do the following, I get my desired output.

```
df['busy'] = np.where((df['hour'] >= '14:00:00') & (df['hour'] <= '23:00:00') & \
                        (df['week_day'] != 'Saturday') & (df['week_day'] != 'Sunday'),'1','0')
```

Any ideas on what mistake am I making in my `hour_bus` function?

Comment: `np.where` understands boolean arrays `if` doesn't it expects a scalar boolean result, so it becomes ambiguous hence the error. It also doesn't make much sense here, changing `and` to `&` is irrelevant, you want to use the boolean mask to mask which rows to overwrite

Comment: @EdChum thank you for quick response, i understand that and `np.where` works fine, but my error is in the function `hour_bus`. Any thoughts why?

Comment: @EdChum Quick question, as I have in the function, there is no problem with returning a new column inside a function right?

Comment: You're using `if` which is the principle problem, if you added `all()`, `any()` etc then it becomes a scalar value, also returning `df['busy'] == 1` doesn't make sense either, that just returns a mask for the entire column

Comment: " I used & instead of and in my if clause. " - you used it **in an `if` clause**, which *has the same problem as `and`, for the same conceptual reason*. Hint: the error message says `truth value` for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
(df['hour'] >= '14:00:00') & (df['hour'] <= '23:00:00')& (df['week_day'] != 'Saturday') & (df['week_day'] != 'Sunday')
```

gives a boolean array, and when you index your `df` with that you'll get a (probably) smaller part of your `df`.

Just to illustrate what I mean:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4]})
mask = df['a'] > 2
print(mask)
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
# 3     True
# Name: a, dtype: bool
indexed_df = df[mask]
print(indexed_df)
#    a
# 2  3
# 3  4
```

However it's still a `DataFrame` so it's ambiguous to use it as expression that requires a truth value (in your case an `if`).

```
bool(indexed_df)
# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

You could use the `np.where` you used - or equivalently:

```
def hour_bus(df):
    mask = (df['hour'] >= '14:00:00') & (df['hour'] <= '23:00:00')& (df['week_day'] != 'Saturday') & (df['week_day'] != 'Sunday')
    res = df['busy'] == 0                             
    res[mask] = (df['busy'] == 1)[mask]  # replace the values where the mask is True
    return res
```

However the `np.where` will be the better solution (it's more readable and probably faster).

Comment: thank you for your answer and explanation. One quick question just to understand, this means that as you and #EdChum noted in the comment, I can not create a function and call, is that correct?

Comment: I just left out the function part because it's not essential to the question and answer. You can always wrap it inside a function :)