# Combine compound condtions

Tags: python

I attempt to refactor the compound conditions

```
if not foo in categories and not foo.capitalize() in categories:
```

to codes like

```
if not foo and foo.capitalize() in categories:
```

It did not work.

Comment: Because foo is not a boolian in this case.

Comment: Put brackets around it to imagine it better:<br> EDIT: I give up. I’m on a phone. Can’t format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you’re aware that this works:

```
if not foo in categories and not foo.capitalize() in categories:
```

It parses as `(not (foo in categories)) and (not (foo.capitalize() in categories)`, i.e.

- foo is not in categories, and
- foo.capitalize() is not in categories.

Since parsing always works the same way and doesn’t guess what you’re most likely to mean, your revised statement

```
if not foo and foo.capitalize() in categories:
```

is parsed as `(not foo) and (foo.capitalize() in categories)`, i.e.

- foo is not, and
- foo.capitalize() is in categories

A cleaner way to write this in Python is with `x not in y` instead of `not x in y` (they’re equivalent):

```
if foo not in categories and foo.capitalize() not in categories:
```

but as far as expressing “neither of these” in a short way here… there’s not much beyond set operators:

```
if not {foo, foo.capitalize()}.intersection(categories):
```

shorthand if `categories` is also a set:

```
if not {foo, foo.capitalize()} & categories:
```

Notice how it’s not much shorter and how it *is* harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In original `if` statement you checking two conditions:

1. `not foo in categories` - will be evaluated to `True` if element `foo` (`str`, I guess) not presented in collection `categories`
2. `not foo.capitalize() in categories` - will be evaluated to `True` if capitalized element `foo`not presented in collection `categories`

In modified `if` statement you checking two completely different conditions:

1. `not foo` - will be evaluated to True if `foo` is empty, `False` or `None`
2. `foo.capitalize() in categories` - will be evaluated to `True` if capitalized element `foo` **presented** in collection `categories`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking if `foo` is `False` and `foo.capitalize()` is in `categories.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific `all` `and` / `not` / `or` cases as you mentioned above, I generally go around with this way:

```
if not all( [foo in categories, foo.capitalize() in categories] ):
```

It makes readability easy and debugging simple too

[see this thread for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182050/3154233)