# How to write multi-line conditions with flake8?

Tags: python-3.x, flake8, linter

I am using `Flake8` to get a standardized code. At the moment, I struggle to find any examples of multi-line `if` conditions.

Example of `if` statement that I have:

`if 'name' in names and data and len(data) > MAX_ACCEPTABLE_LENGTH:`

I cannot change the length of the constant. I tried to do (cond1 and cond2 and cond3) and separate them by lines but cannot get it right.

How can I do it?

Comment: You may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181557/12273727)

Comment: @ChristianHiricoiu I looked into the post that above and similar posts but couldn't find a configuration that worked for `flake8` linter specifically.

Answer (score 3):

According to PEP 8 style guide for ['multiline if statements'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#multiline-if-statements), here's what you are allowed to do :

```
# No extra indentation.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()

# Add a comment, which will provide some distinction in editors
# supporting syntax highlighting.
if (this_is_one_thing and
    that_is_another_thing):
    # Since both conditions are true, we can frobnicate.
    do_something()

# Add some extra indentation on the conditional continuation line.
if (this_is_one_thing
        and that_is_another_thing):
    do_something()
```