# How can I break a line of very long nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, pylint

```
if details['box'] == {} or details['box'][last_box_key].get('timeout', datetime.min) < datetime.now():
```

I tried putting brackets around the dict but I cant seem to break this really long line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling multi-line conditions in 'if' statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/styling-multi-line-conditions-in-if-statements)

Answer (score 0):

You can break the line up using backslashes.

```
if details['box'] == {} or \
    details['box'][last_box_key].get('timeout', datetime.min) \
        < datetime.now():
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [black](https://github.com/psf/black) Python code formatter (note: by default, it formats in-place, i.e. mutates the file, use `--diff` flag to make it just output the changes).
Running `black test.py` formats your code to:

```
if (
    details["box"] == {}
    or details["box"][last_box_key].get("timeout", datetime.min) < datetime.now()
):
```

By adding more keys, you may find out how black will split even longer line:

```
if (
    details["box"] == {}
    or details["box"][last_box_key][another_very_long_key][
        even_more_looooooong_key
    ].get("timeout", datetime.min)
    < datetime.now()
):
```