# Multiple if conditions in Python Selenium (Firefox)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, if-statement, firefox

Yes, I read other threads like: [Styling multi-line conditions in 'if' statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/styling-multi-line-conditions-in-if-statements)

I have this code and I want to check if a specific texts exists on the given page. The code does only work with one condition for some reasons, not with 2 or more.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://example.com/')

if 'ghcjdfghfgh' or 'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

It says yes, even though it not true. I tried the same code with a comma instead of the "or" but still, the same issue.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://example.com/')

if 'ghcjdfghfgh','fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if 'ghcjdfghfgh' in r.text or 'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

Or if you want to extend it, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389611/1387701)'s technique:

```
a_string = "A string is more than its parts!"
matches = ["more", "wholesome", "milk"]

if any(x in a_string for x in matches):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'ghcjdfghfgh' or 'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

this checks if `ghcjdfghfgh` true or `'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text` is true , as all string is true by default. `ghcjdfghfgh` is true

so this equate always true.

If you want to test if any of the string in r.text you can use:

```
if any(x in r.text for x in ['ghcjdfghfgh','fgxhdfghdfyh']):
    print("hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in this statement:

```
if 'ghcjdfghfgh' or 'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
```

you are actually asking 2 different things;
(I):
if 'ghcjdfghfgh' is true!
(II):
if 'fgxhdfghdfyh' is in r.text.
the thing is that (I) is always true; therefore you get 'yes' no matter what!

I can think of 3 ways to get your desired result:
First::

```
if 'ghcjdfghfgh' in r.text or 'fgxhdfghdfyh' in r.text:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

Second::

```
if r.text.find('ghcjdfghfgh') != -1 or r.text.find('fgxhdfghdfyh') != -1:
    print ('Yes')
else:
    print ('No')
```

Third ( THE BEST ONE )::

```
if any(partial_text in r.text for partial_text in ['ghcjdfghfgh','fgxhdfghdfyh']):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```