# Searching for a string in multiple lists with AND conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create an if condition that checks the existence of a certain string and its multiple forms in different lists. The condition currently looks like this.

```
if ("example_string" in node and "example_string" in node_names) or\
        ("string_similar_to_example_string" in node and
         "string_similar_to_example_string" in node_names):
    return response
```

Here `node` is a string that matches the string exactly and `node_names` is a list of strings that has strings matching the example string. This logic right now works, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to write this that makes it readable and clear.

Comment: I guess you can format it probably to make it more readable. Otherwise, storing the conditions in separate variables is an option too.

Comment: @ShameerKashif I did format it using pycharm. But other than this, there is no better way to write this?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181530/styling-multi-line-conditions-in-if-statements

Comment: @ShameerKashif No I actually have gone through that question before and that doesn't match what I am doing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your logic is working here.
So, a small function might help with the code readability.

```
# assuming node and node_names are global here, otherwise you can pass it as well.
def foo(bar):
    """foo function description"""
    if bar in node and bar in node_names:
        return True

if foo("example_string") or foo("string_similar_to_example_string"):
    return response
```

Comment: Yep. This makes my code much better to understand. Thank you! But the answer by @brandt below actually pointed out a hole in my comparion. I am accepting this as the answer but I wish I could've accepted that as well!!

Comment: As I did not check for your comparison, just wanted to point out the solution for better readability. 
Let me upvote his answer for you :).

Answer (score 1):

I like *reducing* functions like `all` or `any`. For instance, I think you could have it done with `any` and then really just organising the sentence.

E.g,

```py
does_match = False

for string_to_lookup in ["example_string", "string_similar"]:
    does_match = string_to_lookup in node and string_to_lookup in node_names)

return response if does_match else None
```

---

*Before I go*, I want to point out something: I *think* your condition for matching the list of strings is wrong; At least, it is different from the match against `node`.

Suppose you have your `"example_string"`, and `node` is `"example_string_yay"` and `node_names` is `["example_string_1", "another_string_bla", "example_what"]`. If you do:

```py
>>> res = "example_string" in node and "example_string" in node_names
>>> print(res)
False
```

but if you do:

```py
>>> res = "example_string" in node and any("example_string" in n for n in node_names)
>>> print(res)
True
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. And I think you might just be right about the incorrect matching on ```node_names```. Let me quickly verify this on my end

Comment: Edit: You are right! Thank you sooo much! The second condition was wrong.  Sorry my score is wayy too less to even upvote your answer. I shall come back and upvote this once I gain enough reputation!